# How to make a <label> text enable or disable an <input> range?

Tags: javascript, html, input, label

I would like the range to toggle itself (minimum / maximum) when I click on the label.
Is that possible with only HTML or CSS ? Do I need some JS?

I have the following code :

```
<label>
        This is the label text
        <input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" value="1" />
</label>
```

Code : https://jsfiddle.net/gjxf60s8/

Comment: care to give more detail about what you need? what do you mean by "toogle itself?" and what have you tried?

Comment: The idea is flawed from the start. The main issue is, that a label is a semantic tag that give assistance to a user, and **screen-readers**.  A focus and a click on a label will also directly select affect the input by default. changing the default behavior will cause the loss of UX and accessibility. If you want to switch the min and max values with each other, you should include a toggle on its own.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Remove the step attribute

```
<label>
        This is the label text
        <input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" value="1" />
</label>
```

2. Try this new js code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var label = document.querySelector('label');
  var rangeInput = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');

  label.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Toggle between min and max values
    if (rangeInput.value > rangeInput.max) {
      rangeInput.value = rangeInput.min;
    } else {
      rangeInput.value = rangeInput.max;
    }
  });
});
```

3. Is implemented here https://jsfiddle.net/tzko8hse/3 (Clicking changes the value to the maximum or minimum defined on the label.)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use js.

Try this code.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var label = document.querySelector('label');
  var rangeInput = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');
  
  label.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Toggle between min and max values
    if (rangeInput.getAttribute('min') === '0') {
      rangeInput.setAttribute('min', '1');
      rangeInput.setAttribute('max', '100');
    } else {
      rangeInput.setAttribute('min', '0');
      rangeInput.setAttribute('max', '1');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I think I wasn't very clear in my question. I didn't want to change the minimum and maximum, I wanted the value to toggle between minimum and maximum when I click on the label.

Using your code as base, here is what worked :

https://jsfiddle.net/v1ausztf/

Comment: try the new code in the new answer :)